# php_apc for Windows - what is the included file php_apc.pdb?

Tags: php, apc

In the zips found here:
http://windows.php.net/downloads/pecl/releases/apc/

There are two files, "php_apc.dll" and "php_apc.pdb"
Any ideas what the .pdb is for?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You don't need the PDB file in order to use the extension.

> PDB stands for Program Database, a proprietary file format (developed by Microsoft) **for storing debugging information** about a program (or, commonly, program modules such as a DLL or EXE). PDB files commonly have a .pdb extension.

http://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Program_database